# Substitute values in all columns of dataframe based in other dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, lapply, substitution

I want to substitute a set of values in all columns of a dataframe. I came with a way to do it, however, I suspect there might be a better way without using `for`.

```
table1<-read.table(text="
col1 col2  col3
C02  M36    MC0237 
C03  C02    M44
C04  M48    F04
F04  M61    M59
F05  M64    M65" ,  header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

table2<-read.table(text="
orig subst
C02  36    
C04  48    
D02  24    
D04  51    
F04  61" ,  header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

table2#<-table2[,c(1,2)]

mylist <- as.character(table2$subst)
names(mylist) <- table2$orig

for (i in 1:length(mylist)){
  table1[which(table1==names(mylist)[i],arr.ind = T)]<-mylist[i]
}
# table1 GOAL, with values substituted in all columns based on table2
# col1 col2 col3
# 1   36  M36  MC0237 # EDITED ABOVE
# 2  C03   36  M44
# 3   48  M48   61
# 4   61  M61  M59
# 5  F05  M64  M65
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner to do this,

```
table1[] <- lapply(table1, function(i) ifelse(grepl(paste(table2$orig, collapse = '|'), i), 
                                                  table2$subst[match(i, table2$orig)], i))
```

which gives

> ```
>   col1 col2 col3
> 1   36  M36  M37
> 2  C03   36  M44
> 3   48  M48   61
> 4   61  M61  M59
> 5  F05  M64  M65
> ```